# How to create multiple v-model bindings with validation?

Tags: vuejs3

From the docs, I can have [multiple `v-model` bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model) by doing this:

```
<script setup>
defineProps({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String
})

defineEmits(['update:firstName', 'update:lastName']) // array syntax
</script>
```

However, I would like to [validate my events with the object syntax](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#events-validation) instead of the array syntax shown here.

But the name has the `update:` prefix, the colon doesn't allow me to use the object syntax. Is there another way to go about achieving that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys in object syntax can be `strings`.

The following should work:

```
defineEmits({
  'update:firstName': (val: string) => true,
  'update:lastName': (val:string) => true,
})
```